# What is the difference between scanf (“%s",a) scanf("%[^\n]s",a) and gets(a) for strings in C programming?

Tags: c, scanf

What is the difference between `scanf("%s")`, `scanf(”%[^\n]s")` and `gets(a)` in C programming?

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", a)

scanf("%s", a)

gets(a)
```

What is the main difference between the three ways of taking character array input?

Comment: `puts()` is for output, at least. What is `a`? If it's an array of char or a pointer to first element of such, then `&a` is wrong as it is either a pointer to array of char, or a pointer to pointer to char.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `"%s[^\n]"`, and not `"%[^\n]"`? Perhaps you need a [good `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)?

Comment: `scanf("%s[^\n]",a)` is just **wrong**. There's a conversion specifier `s` and a **different** conversion specifier `[]`. They are not meant to be combined.

Comment: @FelixPalmen It's not even a conversion specifier, it's a literal match against that sequence (missing `%` in front).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, the way it's written here, it isn't one. But OP obviously **meant** the conversion specifier `[]`. With "there is", I mean in the specification of `scanf()`.

Comment: Writing the `s` **after** `[]` is **still** wrong, but will probably go undetected. They are **different conversion specifiers**, don't combine them.

Comment: Oh, and please don't change code in a question when there are already answers refering to this code.

Comment: Note: Looks like a smart-quote in `scanf(”%[^\n]s")`.  Better to not use word processing programs when writing code which should be  (and w/o the `s`) 
 `scanf("%[^\n]")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, they **all have undefined behavior** for the same reason: They will read a number of characters **you can't know in advance**, but through your pointer, you provide storage where to store this data, and this storage has some fixed size. Therefore, there are **always** inputs possible that will **overflow** your buffer. You should'nt ever use **any** of these lines in your code.

That said:

- `gets()` reads a *line* of input and stores it to your buffer. It also reads the newline character, but this isn't stored. **This function is broken by design**, as there is **no way to use it safely**. Don't ever use it. It has been **removed** from the C standard in C11, so you could only use it with older standards anyways. The correct replacement is `char a[100]; fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin);`. This **will** store the newline character in the buffer, though.
- `scanf("%[^\n]s", ...)` will also read a *line* of input. The `[]` conversion specifier takes a list of accepted or, with `^` in front, rejected characters. So with this syntax, it will accept any character **except** newline. Therefore, the newline character **won't be read** this way. The `s` would be searched in the input  *literally*, it's not what you mean. `s` and `[]` are *different* conversion specifiers. To use this one correctly, you must use the field with like so: `char a[100]; scanf("%99[^\n]", a);`. Note that you have to specify *one less* than your buffer size because `scanf()` doesn't count the `'\0'` character that's appended as an end mark for the string.
- `scanf("%s", ...)` reads a "*word*", that is it stops at the first *whitespace* character. To use this correctly, as above, use something like `char a[100]; scanf("%99s", a);`.

Comment: Love the phrase "broken by design".... I know what you mean, but it almost sounds like the designers _meant_ for `gets()` to be broken ;)

Comment: Haha, never thought about *this* with such a phrase. Of course I just mean the design is wrong to an extent making it impossible to "fix" in the implementation.

Comment: "scanf("%s", ...) reads a "word", that is it stops at the first whitespace character." omits the parts that leading white-space are  read and discarded, then reading a "word" commences.

Answer (score 5):

`scanf("%s",a);` will skip over leading whitespace characters in the input, and will match characters until a whitespace character is encountered (or until end-of-file is reached), storing them in the array indicated by the argument. Note that this is susceptible to buffer overflow, so it is best to include a width specifer that provides a maximum number of characters to read from the input. For example, if `a` is an array of 100 `char`s, `%99s` should be used; this leaves space for the `\0` terminator that is automatically added by `scanf()`.

Neither `scanf("%s[^\n]",a);` nor `scanf("%[^\n]s", a);` is probably what was meant, and instead this should be: `scanf("%[^\n]",a);`. The `%[]` is a *scanset* directive. There is no need to follow the `%[]` directive with an `s`, which would only tell `scanf()` to match a literal `s` in the input after finishing with `%[]`. The scanset directive matches characters described within the brackets and assigns them to the corresponding argument. When a match fails, that character is placed back in the input stream. Here, the `^\n` indicates that all characters *except* for newline characters should be matched, so this directive will match characters until a newline is encountered, and the newline will remain in the input stream. The same advice about specifying a maximum width applies here as well: `%99[^\n]` to avoid buffer overflow, if `a` is an array of 100 `char`s. Note that the `%[^\n]` directive will match any character that is not a `\n`, including other whitespace characters. This means that it will *not* skip over leading whitespace characters (but a leading `\n` in the input will cause the directive to immediately fail, without making an assignment), in contrast to `%s`, and will read *lines* of input containing spaces.

`puts(a);` does not read input, but is an output function. Note that this function prints a newline after printing its argument. Perhaps you meant to include `gets()` in this list of methods to gather input.

[`gets(a);` is an unsafe function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) that was deprecated in C99, and completely removed from the language in C11. You should never use this function for any reason. This function fetches a line of input, reading characters until a newline character is encountered, or until end-of-file is reached. The newline character is discarded; it is not stored in the array indicated by `a`, and it is not returned to the input stream. For this reason, when `gets()` was used in the past, it worked well with `puts()`, which automatically prints a newline character after printing its argument.

Finally, for a little more information, there is `fgets()`. This function fetches a line of input, but takes a size argument so that buffer overflow may be avoided. Given my earlier example of `char a[100];`, `fgets()` would be called like this:

```
fgets(a, 100, stdin);
```

or sometimes:

```
fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin);
```

Here, `fgets()` reads at most *one character less* than the number specified by the size argument, allowing space for a `\0`, which is always added. If the `\n` is read, it is stored in `a`. Since the newline is not discarded, `puts()` does not work as well here; often the newline needs to be removed after taking input with `fgets()`.

Comment: Sorry, my last edit happened during your elaborative answer. OP obviously didn't think a second before posting this, please feel free to edit it back, I'll abandon this now...

Comment: Do you mean the `gets()` that is now in the answer? I just saw that and was updating....

Comment: Ok then ... at least the code in the question now is what OP meant. I wished people would take a second to proof-read what they're asking before hitting the post button :o

Comment: A part missing is the result of `scanf("%[^\n]",a);` when the first character is `'\n'`.  `scanf("%[^\n]",a);` fails to save anything in `a` in that case.

Comment: @chux-- I thought that I covered this case with "(but a leading `\n` in the input will cause the directive to immediately fail, without making an assignment)"....